# C++ Remove Evenly numbered words from a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

having some issues with implementing the logic for one homework problem. The platform I am using currently is Visual Studio 2013 and am a beginner. We are using the terminal (command prompt) built in with the application to get the input and output. We are currently using "CIN" and "COUT". The problem is as follows:

"Write a program that asks the user for a sentence and then strips out every even-numbered word. For example: "All The Presidents Men" would become "All Presidents". Return the modified sentence to main() function using an output parameter and then display both the original and modified sentences".

I've been trying to apply this with logic that puts each word into an array/vector, and removes each word with an index of an even number. I have yet to successfully accomplish this and am seeking some assistance from you experts!

Thank you much.

Comment: Please be a little more specific about what you have tried and what the problem is (e.g. by showing us your code).

Answer (score 1):

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/AVWUFY)

```
std::string line;

// get input from cin stream 
if (std::getline(cin, line)) // check for success
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string word;

    // The simplest way to split our line with a ' ' delimiter is using istreamstring + getline
    std::istringstream stream;
    stream.str(line);

    // Split line into words and insert them into our vector "words"
    while (std::getline(stream, word, ' '))
        words.push_back(word);

    if (words.size() % 2 != 0) // if word count is not even, print error.
        std::cout << "Word count not even " << words.size() << " for string: " << line;
    else
    {
        //Remove the last word from the vector to make it odd
        words.pop_back();

        std::cout << "Original: " << line << endl;
        std::cout << "New:";

        for (std::string& w : words)
            cout << " " << w;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this

```
int count = -1;
for (auto it =input.begin();it!=input.end();){
if(*it==' '){
    count++;it++;
    if (count%2==0){
       while (it != input.end()){
            if (*it==' ')break;
            it=input.erase (it);
       }
   }else it++;
 }else it++;
}`
```